# Сколько в русском языке членораздельных звуков?

Tags: языкознание

Сколько в русском языке членораздельных звуков?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я знаю, зависит от того, какой звук считать фонемой, а какой — аллофоном.
Разные лингвистические школы определяют то, является ли той или иной звук аллофоном или же полноценной фонемой, по-разному, так что и количество фонем тоже разнится.
Вот сейчас посмотрел в Википедии и выяснил, что Московская фонологическая школа выделяет 39 фонем, а Петербургская — 43.
Однако учтите, что фонема и звук — не одно и то же.
Если считать все звуки, которые могут появиться в русской речи (в т. ч. в результате дефектов дикции, шепелявости и т. п.), их, конечно, будет гораздо больше.

Насколько я знаю, дело обстоит вот так. Но мне нельзя верить, я лишь дилетант. Надеюсь, что знающие люди придут и поправят ошибки и неточности, если я их допустил.

Answer (score 0):

Есть теория о 48 членораздельных звуках:
[Смотреть тут](http://www.newtheory.ru/linguistics/teoriya-o-48-chlenorazdelnih-zvukah-v-russkom-yazike-t506.html)

Answer (score 0):

Fuchoin Kazuki, это особенно интересно в свете того, что автор той "теории" и этого вопроса, видимо, один и тот же человек. (:Смайлик-ФейсомОбТэйбл:)

Членораздельной бывает речь, а не звуки. Вопрос - ффтопку. Смайлик(:АфтырьВыпейЯду:)

Answer (score 0):

. "Вопрос - ффтопку. Смайлик(:АфтырьВыпейЯду:)"
behemothus! Класс! В русском языке разбираюсь - в его компьютерно-жаргонном варианте - нет. Так называемый "Олбанский " язык читать трудно. Хотя занятно.  Смысл  выражения, в общем, понятен. Может, просветите, а что значит "Автор жжет" (на олбанском  - аффтар жжот?) - это одобрение означает или нет?
Уважаемые модераторы! Я на форуме первый день... Может. этому вопросу место не здесь, тогда перенесите в нужное место. Но я спрашиваю именно у behemothus. Спасибо.

Comment: А Вы знаете, что к настоящему времени создан особый "Учебник для написания учебников по русскому языку", где подвергнута беспощадной критике  текущая теория русского языка? Между прочим , рецензентами  этого учебника являются 4 доктора наук. Смотреть здесь:
http://www.litsovet.ru/index.php/material.read?material_id=378287
http://www.litsovet.ru/index.php/material.read?material_id=378960

Comment: Тролль Иван Стрельцов!
Мы знаем, какой беспощадной критике подвергаются форумские пакостники, особенно те, которые не в состоянии членораздельно высказать свою мысль.
Между прочим, вам уже неоднократно было сказано, что вы путаете (сознательно видимо) звуки какого-то языка и звуки речи вообще. Последние могут быть (не)членоразденые, но не первые.

Comment: И хватить рекламить собственный бездарные потуги навести тень на русский язык.

Comment: **Ларf**
Я боюсь, модераторы все мои ответы модераторы поудаляют, но пока это не произошло.
"Аффтырь Жжот" (в разных написаниях) означает, что сказано что-то смешное, креативное, оригинальное. Как правило это, конечно, одобрение.